# Vue.js - Displaying JSON results not working correctly

Tags: javascript, json, vue.js

Before I start this question I am 100% new to vue.js so I may be missing something simple. I've looked through the documentation endlessly and still haven't got a soloution to my problem.

I'm just building a very simple example as practice, where I fill a form and it saves to my DB, but also loads the records I've saved automatically.

This is where it gets strange, when I plug into https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users the JSON data displays correctly in my app.

When I pug into my own backend code, valid JSON is returned but it doesn't display correctly.

This is where I call my Data:

```
created: function(){
          this.$http.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users') // JSON service that is working
          this.$http.get('http://localhost:8888/vue_testing/users/get/') // My JSON Service that isn't
            .then(function(response){
              console.log(response.data);
              this.users = response.data;
            });
        }
```

Note I am getting back valid JSON from both services.

My valid JSON: http://take.ms/lIa3u

But displays like this: http://take.ms/6dOEL

jsonplaceholder Valid JSON: http://take.ms/VCwKZ

And displays like this:http://take.ms/Ne3fw

This is my complete component code:

```
    <template>
    <div class="users">
      <h1>Users</h1>
      <form v-on:submit="add_user">
        <input type="text" v-model="new_user.name" placeholder="Enter name" /><br />
        <input type="text" v-model="new_user.email" placeholder="Enter email" />
        <input type="submit" value="submit">
      </form>
      <ul>
        <li v-for="user in users">
          {{user.name}}: {{user.email}}
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default{
        name: 'users',
        //Props can accept values from outside the component
        data(){
            return{
              new_user: {},
              users: []
            }
        },
        methods:{
          add_user: function(e){
            //console.log('Add');
            this.$http.post('http://localhost:8888/vue_testing/users/set/', this.new_user)
              .then(response => {
                console.log(response);
              }, error => {
                console.log(error);
            });
            e.preventDefault();
          }
        },
        created: function(){
          //this.$http.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users')
          this.$http.get('http://localhost:8888/vue_testing/users/get/')
            .then(function(response){
              console.log(response.data);
              this.users = response.data;
            });
        }
    }
</script>

<style scoped>
</style>
```

Again I'm totally new to vue.js, any help in solving this is appricieated. Thanks.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you want `this.users = response.data['DATA']`

Comment: @Dan, this is not displaying anything now. How come the external source https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users works without the ['Data'] then? Thanks for your time.

Comment: In your template you also need to do `{{ user[1] }}: {{ user[2] }}`. Your data is in an array format, not an object so you can't use string keys to access it, only numbers

Comment: This didn't work either. I have a feeling it's something to do with the source as I did pass back the exact same data that I'm getting from the working and it still didn't work. Thanks for your time. I'll dig around some more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While jsonplaceholder is sending you an array of objects:

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Leanne Grehem",
        ...
    }
]
```

You are sending from your backend an object which holds first the columns, and second a two dimensional array for the data:

```
{
    "COLUMNS": ["ID", "NAME", ...],
    "DATA": [
        [1, "Leanne Grehem, ...],
        [2, "John Doe, ...],
    ]
}
```

I would advise you to change your backend so your response looks like that of the jsonplaceholder. Otherwise you would have to make objects out of arrays. Like below:

```
    created: function(){
      //this.$http.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users')
      this.$http.get('http://localhost:8888/vue_testing/users/get/')
        .then(function(response){
          console.log(response.data);
          let users = [];
          const responseData = response.data['DATA']; // Get DATA key from your response
          for (user of responseData) { // iterate
              users.push( { id: user[0], name: user[1] } );  // create object out of array
          }
          this.users = users;
        });
    }
```

Edit: typo

Comment: Yes I have tried this already. I mentioned above that I put the exact same json code in the response from my own server and I still get the exact same issue. Thanks for your time and answer

Comment: Ok got it working, For some reason there was alot of white space being generated in the back end. Working fine now thanks for your time.